# Screening with a new company, previous job a start-up

Tags: startup, pre-screening

I recently received an offer for a job with a new company who have sent out a screening questionnaire with a request for 5 years of employment history. For the past 2.5 years I have worked for a large company as a full time employee but prior to that I helped a friend at his startup.

It was a relatively short period of about 4 months which I started when he received funding from a regional business development agency. We agreed to use 20% for the business and split the remaining in half for us to live on over those four months. After those four months the business was unsuccessful and we went our separate ways. This business grant was the only money we received, we made no money from customers.

The company was officially registered with the UK government. It is apparently still active according to Companies House. I am not listed as an officer and I did not sign a contract of employment. I did not receive any payslips nor did I pay any tax. I also did not create or send any invoices.

How do I put this down in the screening questionnaire? There are choices for permanent, agency, freelancer/self-employed, work experience, education or unemployed.

Comment: "nor did I pay any tax" - you are legally required to pay tax on anything over £12k per annum (at the moment). If you are ever audited and they look at your bank records ... Perhaps ask a tax preparer if you can make retroactive payments without getting into trouble? The authorities might ask a few questions, but will be generally happy that you are coming forward and paying.  Btw, would you name the regional business development agency? I wouldn't mind a grant myself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I put this down in the screening questionnaire? There are
>   choices for permanent, agency, freelancer/self-employed, work
>   experience, education or unemployed.

I would categorize it as "freelancer/self-employed" with enough comments to explain the unique nature of the situation.

> I did not receive any payslips nor did I pay any tax.

Was that done legally? If not, you might want to omit those details.

Comment: Few contradiction need to be clarified. If  you are not registered in the company how you have worked..How the salary was received it must be through banking transaction. You can categorized it as self employed